# Is there an equivalent to Vegas' "select to end" feature in DaVinci Resolve?

Tags: davinci-resolve

[Vegas had an option](http://vegaspro.helpmax.net/en/using-vegas-software/editing-events-on-the-timeline/selecting-events/) in the context menu after right clicking on a track to select all clips to the end of that track. Does Resolve have the same feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called ["Select Clips Forward On This Track"](http://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/DaVinciResolve/DaVinci_Resolve_Mac_Keyboard_Shortcuts_June_2014.pdf), and it's activated by placing the playhead (the tall orange marker) over the first clip you want to select and doing one of the following:

- Select Clips Forward On This Track: <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Select Clips Forward On All Tracks: <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

There are more of these available in the Timeline menu ("Select Clips Backward", "Select Clips Forward").